# Spring Cloud Data Flow in Open Shift

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I want to deploy SCDF in **Open Shift** , Are the following components are compatible with open shift.

1. Spring Cloud Data Flow Server
2. Skipper Server.

Answer (score 0):

SCDF and Skipper are upstream K8s compatible. Openshift and other K8s distros are possible; assuming they are compatible with the upstream, as well.

Here's the latest K8s version compatibility chart; there's an update to this chart via: [spring-io/dataflow.spring.io#359](https://github.com/spring-io/dataflow.spring.io/pull/359).